# Google Spreadsheet sum when filtering

Tags: google-sheets

I have spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

Now when I filter on a company I want the total to display the sum of the whole of B column.

Since I am very new to spreadsheets I was hoping someone could help me on how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649)

```
=SUBTOTAL(9, B2:B20)
```